# How can I include the status message in an email template after changing the status of an order using Store?

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, tags

In the back-end at order details you can add a message while changing the status of the order. I want to use this information in the email templates, but I can't find the appropriate tag for the message.

Comment: Remember to mark an answer as accepted if it answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

Go to

EE --> Store --> Settings --> Email templates

There's quite a lot of information, nicely described.

I think the tag you're looking for is {order_status_message}